# Where can I find a proper library of free adventures for Fate Core and Accelerated?

Tags: published-adventures, fate-core, fate-accelerated, online-resources

I can't find a proper repository of premade adventures, and I'm pretty lost as to what I'm going to GM with Fate Accelerated. I'm willing to take Core adventures and try to adapt them, but it's not preferable.

Comment: Much of the content here is pay what you want, which includes free. http://drivethrurpg.com/browse/pub/2152/Evil-Hat-Productions-LLC/subcategory/3924_19296/Fate-Core?affiliate_id=24139 — the Fate Adventures & Worlds line is being funded by way of our Patreon campaign at http://patreon.com/evilhat and has produced probably the largest single population of "free" adventure and setting content for Fate Core & Accelerated. Third parties may be making theirs as well, but that's more scattered.

Comment: @FredHicks Welcome back. This particular Q&A system breaks down around answers left in comments though: answers need to formally go in the answer field where they can receive due attention like peer review, edits, and voting. Answers left in comments get wiped out (sometimes very quickly, sometimes not). You may wish to check out our [tour] for a quick overview of the site's functionality, though you may already be quite up to speed.

Answer (score 10):

Evil Hat has a series of pay what you want adventures called [World of Adventure](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse.php?keywords=World%20of%20Adventure&manufacturers_id=2152&x=0&y=0&author=&artist=&pfrom=&pto=) that can easily be run in FAE. The [Fate Codex](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse/pub/4353/Magpie-Games/subcategory/8460_22821/Fate-Codex) also comes with FAE quick start adventures. Aside from these, pretty much any Fate Core adventure can be turned into an FAE adventure.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning: search the very same drive thru RPG for [Fate adventure supplements with the keyword 'accelerated'](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse.php?filters=0_2110_44284_0_0&keywords=accelerated). It produces a couple of Worlds of Adventure designed for Fate Accelerated specifically, and other FAE adventures.

Answer (score 3):

## RPGGeek

As with many "directory" questions, the geek is your friend.

1. Go to the [RPG page for Fate Core on RPGGeek](http://rpggeek.com/rpg/203/fate-core).
2. Under "Linked Items" select "Scenario / Adventure / Module" from the category dropdown.
   It includes FAE items, as explained on the page and on the Evil Hat site.